# DropZone parallelUploads not working I have set parallelUploads to 10 but it is uploading 20 in one request

Tags: dropzone

I have DropZone to upload files.

I have set parallelUploads to 10. I am dropping 125 files and I am getting just one request to server and there are 20 files in one request. I have also set parallelUploads to 9999 but again just 20 files I receive on server.

Here is the code:

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
//maxFilesize: 20 is 20 MB
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzoneForm", {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    method: 'post',
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 10,    //  Also set to 9999 but not working
    maxFileSize: 4,
    autoProcessQueue: false
});
myDropzone.on('addedfiles', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        sendFiles();
    }, 1);
});
myDropzone.on('addedfile', function (file) {
    var iFilesLength = myDropzone.files.length;
    if (iFilesLength > 0) {
        var bFileFound = false;
        for (var iiFileLength = iFilesLength - 1; iiFileLength >= 0; iiFileLength--) {
            if (file.name == myDropzone.files[iiFileLength].name) {
                if (bFileFound)
                    myDropzone.removeFile(myDropzone.files[iiFileLength]);
                else bFileFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
});

function sendFiles() {
    if (myDropzone.files.length > 0) {
        myDropzone.processFiles(myDropzone.files);
    }
}

myDropzone.on('successmultiple', function (file, responseText) {
    $("#myResponse").html(responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue of php.ini. As we know there are default configuration settings set in php.ini. In this file default value is max_file_uploads = 20 so change this to max_file_uploads = 99999.

Refresh your server and see it will work.

And problem solved.